# html5 on chromium

Tags: 16.04, chromium

How do you get html5 videos to work in Chromium?

I have tried doing:

```
sudo apt-get chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra
```

but it returned this error:

```
E: Invalid operation chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra
```

Comment: Should work out of the box. Link to broken web site?

Answer (score 2):

What is

```
sudo apt-get chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra
```

suppose to do?

I would suggest

```
sudo apt install chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra
```

---

You probably need to do this too:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge chromium-codecs-ffmpeg
```